# Android databinding not working on initial creation of view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

## Description

First you need to know I have created a custom UI view which is basically a dial whose value you can change by dragging on it. `preValue` is the position of the dial at all times (in real-time, while dragging it) and `value` is set to `preValue` when the dial is released.

1. In my `ViewModel` I initialize a `LiveData` like this:

```
val bpm = MutableLiveData<Int>(60)
```

2. I bind this to my custom control's `value` in my layout:

```xml
<com.example.app.view.DialPicker
    android:id="@+id/dial_picker"
    ...
    android:value="@={viewmodel.bpm}" />
```

3. The custom control has these properties:

```
var value: Int = 0
    set(v) {
        if (field != v) {
            val previous = field
            field = v
            onValueChangeListener?.onValueChange(this, previous, field)
            preValue = v
        }
    }

var preValue: Int = 0
    set(v) {
        if (field != v) {
            val previous = field
            field = v
            onPreValueChangeListener?.onValueChange(this, previous, field)
            onVisualValueChanged(field)
        }
    }
```

NOTE: `preValue` is set to `value` whenever `value` is set.

4. I have a `TextView` in my layout which is bound to the `preValue` property of my custom control:

```xml
<TextView
    ...
    android:text="@{Integer.toString(dialPicker.preValue)}" />
```

## Problem

When I start the app, the `TextView` shows 0 (or whatever I set `var preValue` default value as in the custom control definition).

It should be showing `60`, because of the logic I outlined above.

I've debugged to make sure that the `preValue` setter is run when initializing the fragment, and it is.

When manipulating the control, the `TextView` works as expected, so I feel like the databinding should be setup correctly.

## Binding Adapters:

```
@InverseBindingMethods(
    InverseBindingMethod(type=DialPicker::class, attribute="android:value"),
    InverseBindingMethod(type=DialPicker::class, attribute="android:preValue")
)
class DialPickerBindingAdapter {
    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        @BindingAdapter(value=["android:onValueChange", "android:valueAttrChanged"], requireAll= false)
        fun setValueListener(view: DialPicker, listener: OnValueChangeListener?, attrChange: InverseBindingListener?) {
            if (attrChange == null) {
                view.onValueChangeListener = listener
            } else {
                view.onValueChangeListener = object : OnValueChangeListener {
                    override fun onValueChange(picker: DialPicker, oldVal: Int, newVal: Int) {
                        listener?.onValueChange(picker, oldVal, newVal)
                        attrChange.onChange()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @JvmStatic
        @BindingAdapter(value=["android:onPreValueChange", "android:preValueAttrChanged"], requireAll= false)
        fun setPreValueListener(view: DialPicker, listener: OnValueChangeListener?, attrChange: InverseBindingListener?) {
            if (attrChange == null) {
                view.onPreValueChangeListener = listener
            } else {
                view.onPreValueChangeListener = object : OnValueChangeListener {
                    override fun onValueChange(picker: DialPicker, oldVal: Int, newVal: Int) {
                        listener?.onValueChange(picker, oldVal, newVal)
                        attrChange.onChange()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a binding adapter for the value? Do you have the "value" attr defined for the view?

Comment: I've edited the question with my binding adapter definitions. I have defined `value` and `preValue` in attrs.xml

Comment: Probably not the solution, but when using your custom bindings, you should not use the `android` namespace in your xml layout. That is kind of reserved for framework-internal atttributes. Instead, define your own. I usually name it `binding:xxxx` with the following xmlns declaration: `xmlns:binding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`